# Throw custom exception Azure mobile app easy tables script

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am trying to write a custom script for easy tables in Azure mobile app and have the following code. When executing I get an error stating "Can't set headers after they are sent". What am I doing wrong?

```
table.insert(function (context) {  
  var request = context.req;  
  var response = context.res;  
  var customer = context.item;  
  var isactive = customer.active;
  if (isactive ==="false"){  
      response.status(406).send('Customer Error`);  
      //response.end();  
      return;
  } 
  else {  
      return context.execute();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally caused by res.send or res.json being called more than once per request. I copied your code into a table in a blank app and couldn't reproduce the error. There must be something elsewhere in your application that is causing the error.

If you use something like postman to POST to the table endpoint, do you see the 406 response as well as the error in the console, or just the error? If you see the 406 response, the res.send is being executed somewhere in the pipeline AFTER the 406 is returned. If not, it's happening before.

Have you got other middleware that is executing?

Comment: Another thing that just occurred to me - what version are you using? There was an issue that was resolved in a version that was released a couple of months ago.

Comment: It was posting both on the console as well as on postman. It was posting on the console after I added a catch block and logged the error. I did not have other middleware. But I finally got it to work by adding a custom middleware for this piece of code.

Comment: I however have a new problem. After executing and querying using the custom middleware, i come back to the table.insert(function (context) ). How do I manipulate the response that goes back to the browser (for example I want to delete a password field) if I am using the return context.execute() method?

Comment: context.execute simply returns a promise that yields the results. You can call context.execute().then(function (results) { results.map(x => { delete x.password; return x }) })